# Integrate $\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}{\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I need help with this integral: $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\cos^2x}dx$$ I tried substitution and other methods, but all have lead me to this expression: $$2\int\sqrt{\tan x}(1+\tan^2 x)dx$$ where I can't calculate anything... Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* what's the derivative of $\tan x$?

Comment: Hint: rewrite as $$\int \sec^2 x\sqrt{\tan x}dx$$

Comment: This forum would be so much better if people only offered hints like you have done. Much more beneficial than full solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Let $u = \tan x$ then $du  = \sec^2 x\ \  dx = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} dx$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int \dfrac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\cos^2 x} dx = 
\int \sqrt{\tan x} \; d(\tan x) = \dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{(\tan x)^3} +C
$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $t=\tan x$; then $\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu t=\dfrac1{\cos^2x}\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x$ so the integral becomes $$\int\sqrt t\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu t = \frac 23 (t)^{\frac32}=\frac23\tan t\sqrt{\tan t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, your integral simplifies to
$$2\int\sqrt{\tan x}\ \sec^2x\ dx$$
If one makes the substitution $u=\tan x$, one gets $du=\sec^2x dx$, which reduces our integral to
$$2\int u^{1/2}du$$
$$=2\frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2}+C$$
$$=\frac{4u^{3/2}}{3}+C$$
$$=\frac{4\tan^{3/2}x}{3}+C$$